# Azureml : error "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." while creating Tabular Dataset from Azure Blob Storage file

Tags: ssl, openssl, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have a new error using Azure ML maybe due to the Ubuntu upgrade to 22.04 which I did yesterday.

I have a workspace azureml created through the portal and I can access it whitout any issue with python SDK

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config("config/config.json")
ws.get_details()
```

output

```
{'id': '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/gr_louis/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/azml_lk',
 'name': 'azml_lk',
 'identity': {'principal_id': 'XXXXX',
  'tenant_id': 'XXXXX',
  'type': 'SystemAssigned'},
 'location': 'westeurope',
 'type': 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces',
 'tags': {},
 'sku': 'Basic',
 'workspaceid': 'XXXXX',
 'sdkTelemetryAppInsightsKey': 'XXXXX',
 'description': '',
 'friendlyName': 'azml_lk',
 'keyVault': '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/gr_louis/providers/Microsoft.Keyvault/vaults/azmllkXXXXX',
 'applicationInsights': '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/gr_louis/providers/Microsoft.insights/components/azmllkXXXXX',
 'storageAccount': '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/gr_louis/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/azmllkXXXXX',
 'hbiWorkspace': False,
 'provisioningState': 'Succeeded',
 'discoveryUrl': 'https://westeurope.api.azureml.ms/discovery',
 'notebookInfo': {'fqdn': 'ml-azmllk-westeurope-XXXXX.westeurope.notebooks.azure.net',
  'resource_id': 'XXXXX'},
 'v1LegacyMode': False}
```

I then use this workspace `ws` to upload a file (or a directory) to Azure Blob Storage like so

```
from azureml.core import Dataset

ds = ws.get_default_datastore()

Dataset.File.upload_directory(
    src_dir="./data",
    target=ds,
    pattern="*dataset1.csv",
    overwrite=True,
    show_progress=True
)
```

which again works fine and outputs

```
Validating arguments.
Arguments validated.
Uploading file to /
Filtering files with pattern matching *dataset1.csv
Uploading an estimated of 1 files
Uploading ./data/dataset1.csv
Uploaded ./data/dataset1.csv, 1 files out of an estimated total of 1
Uploaded 1 files
Creating new dataset

{
  "source": [
    "('workspaceblobstore', '//')"
  ],
  "definition": [
    "GetDatastoreFiles"
  ]
}
```

My file is indeed uploaded to Blob Storage and I can see it either on azure portal or on azure ml studio (ml.azure.com).
[image: uploaded_file]

The error comes up when I try to create a Tabular dataset from the uploaded file. The following code doesn't work :

```
from azureml.core import Dataset

data1 = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(
    path=[(ds, "dataset1.csv")]
)
```

and it gives me the error :

```
ExecutionError: 
Error Code: ScriptExecution.DatastoreResolution.Unexpected
Failed Step: XXXXXX
Error Message: ScriptExecutionException was caused by DatastoreResolutionException.
  DatastoreResolutionException was caused by UnexpectedException.
    Unexpected failure making request to fetching info for Datastore 'workspaceblobstore' in subscription: 'XXXXXX', resource group: 'gr_louis', workspace: 'azml_lk'. Using base service url: https://westeurope.experiments.azureml.net. HResult: 0x80131501.
      The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
| session_id=XXXXXX
```

After some research, I assumed it might be due to openssl version (which now is 1.1.1) but I am not sure and I surely don't know how to fix it...any ideas ?

Comment: So what did you see in the inner exception?

Comment: Truth is...I have tried but I could not figure out how to get this "inner exception". I don't have any log files and a try except always returns me the same ExecutionError

Answer (score -1):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-connect-data-ui?tabs=credential) there is no direct procedure to convert the file dataset into tabular dataset. Instead, we can create a workspace and that creates two storage methods (blobstorage which is the default storage, file storage). The SSL will be taken care by workspace.
We can create a datastore in the workspace and connect that to the blob storage.

Follow the procedure to do the same.

[image]

Create a workspace

[image]

If we want, we can create a dataset.

[image]

We can create from local files of datastore.

To choose a datastore, first we need to have a file in the datastore

[image]

Goto Datastores and click on create dataset. Observe that the name is workspaceblobstorage(default).

[image]

Fill the details and see that the dataset type is Tabular.

[image]

In the path, we will be having the local files path and can check there, under the **select or create a datastore**, it is showing default storage as blob.

[image]

After uploading, we can wee the name in this section which is a datastore and tabular dataset.

In your workspace created, check whether the public access is **Disabled or Enabled**. If disabled, it will not allow to access due to lack of SSL. Checkout the image below. After enabling, use the same procedure which was implemented till now.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply although it doesn't quite answer my question...first I would need to use python SDK azureml and second I do have a workspace with a storage account associated on which i can upload a file but the error occurs when trying to generate a Tabular dataset from delimited uploaded file. However, I tried creating a dataset through azuml studio portal and it works. Which actually puzzles me even more !

Comment: Before using the code block, it is suggestable to check for **public access** of the workspace and the resources, which may not be enabled by default some cases. I have updated the answer to show, where we can enable public access of all network resources. The remaining python procedure used until now will be same.

Comment: I checked and the public access was already enabled...

Comment: Replace the existing code 

`data1 = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=[(ds, "dataset1.csv")])`


with


`data1= Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=(datastore,'path_of_dataset'))`

Inner exception occurred because using list instead of tuple while calling the datastore.

Comment: well I tried this also already but it doesn't change anything...and worth to mention, this code worked perfectly before ubuntu 22.04 upgrade which is why I assume it has something to do with openssl version (3.0.2 in ubuntu 22.04 vs 1.1.1 in ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: have you comment out the `ssl_conf` value in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`? Comment it once and re-execute.

Comment: I have with no success

Comment: Have you tried to do `Uninstall OpenSSL 1.0.x`.

Kindly checkout the notes about Open SSL restrictions in Ubuntu 22.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405100/i-have-problem-with-new-ubuntu-22-04-and-openssl-3-0-2#:~:text=Ubuntu%2022.04%20upgraded%20OpenSSL%20to%20version%203.0.2%2C%20which,options%20flags%20that%20permits%20connection%20despite%20the%20vulnerability%3A